# How to add images to Git webpage?

Tags: html, css, github, web

I have the images in the repository, and I've linked to them via URL in my HTML file, but when I check the webpage on Github, the images do not appear.

> 

Am I doing something wrong? How is it usually done?

Name and info redacted for my privacy.

I of course immediately ruled out the mistake of linking the images to locations on my PC
I uploaded the images, then changed the link to them in the HTML file, which worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your naming convention?

If anyone has the same problem.
GitHub Pages are case-sensitive. Not only for folders but also for image names.